# Silently move api resources to another url

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've got api written with WepApi 2 tightly coupled with main web site. 
I've decided to decouple it to another web app to keep things more isolated.

I've followed such steps:

1. Extract all the API controllers to another project
2. Creat attribute to redirect all the users currently using our old URL to the new one. For such reasons I've used [307 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) because we should keep user's request's verb and request payload.

   ```
       var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect); //307
       response.Headers.Location = new Uri($"{appConfig.ApiAppDomain}" + "/" + request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath + request.RequestUri.Query);
       return response;
   ```

In common it works nice. Client got 307 and then follows to the URL in `Location` header.

The problem is here: the main web app is `https` and the new api is `http`. When I'm using postman it behave strange and do replace the `POST` request with `GET` request with all request's body cutting. Not good at all and strange because `307` doesn't allow to change the method and the payload.

So here are the couple of questions:

1. What is the best way to handle this https -> http redirection?
2. Whether it is good solution at all or not?
3. What is the best solution to silently move our users to new api url?

Comment: Usually new routes are implemented with versioning, like v2 in the route or header. But since you have created a complete new API, IMO you shouldn't redirect. Treat both as seperate API's. But do mention to your clients that the old API is supported until a certain date and then will be turned off. As a side note, I would 'upgrade' the new API to https.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

302,301 etc Redirects for that matter will be GET requests only .However for 307 technically the browser can make a POST request .More details [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect) .But it is not a good idea to have a redirect which will make unnecessary round trips for every request.Also it may cause other issues like cross domain calls(If you are making Ajax REST API call or browsers will verify all the resources are loaded from https only([Mixed content warning](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2625928/only-secure-content-is-displayed-notification-in-internet-explorer-9))

What is the best way to handle this https -> http redirection?

> we should not do redirection as it can cause many issues as I was explaining above

Whether it is good solution at all or not?

> Redirection is not a good solution in this scenario.

What is the best solution to silently move our users to new api url?

> The best solution in this scenario in my opinion is to setup a transparent proxy which will do https offloading as well. This will make zero change in your client side also.Here's how we can set it up.

- Setup reverse proxy in IIS for any request which goes to your API.

  - refer  [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/) ,[setup reverse proxy for api](http://www.dotnetspeak.com/webapi/setting-up-reverse-proxy-for-web-api-in-iis/) and [this](https://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr)
    -Once you follow any of the above article ,you will have a urlrewrite rule like this

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <configuration>
          <system.webServer>
              <rewrite>
                  <rules>
                      <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                          <match url="api/(.*)" />
                          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server2/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                          <conditions>
                          </conditions>
                  </rule>
              </rules>
          </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`

In this above urlrewrite rule,you will be forwarding the request to server2 if the requested url contains **api** which will be over http.So till this server the request will come on https and from there it will go to server 2 on http.but this happens wihout the client's knowledge. And this will be local request(not over internet) and the latency is negligible.So the flow will be like this

> Browser =>https(https://example.com/api/products/2) =>
>   http(http://server2/api/products/2)

- Remove the API code from your original website completely. Including the redirect logic ,this will make your website completely free of API implementation

just summarizing the advantages of this approach

1. At the client side there is no change required, Clients will not even know that something like this is happening. So no extra round trips on the client side.
2. Your traffic will be full https and no https to http outside your main website.
3. If you have the main website and API calls in the main website, it does not create cross domain calls or mixed content warnings.
   4.You have completely isolated your main website from API code.

Comment: An update for you. My main site is on https and I want to rewrite to http. Doesn't work so far))

Comment: do you have two different websites ? or u have created  new webapplication inside IIS instead of a new website

Comment: if it is just another application and you are hosting inside the same website  only,still this approach works .In that case you do not do proxy but just url rewrite will work fine. Browser =>https(https://example.com/api/products/2) => (newapp created inside iis)   .so in that case u only have to rewrite the url to api/products/2 to newapp/api/products/2. Is this what you want?