# Azure. URL Rewrite. Authentication mode forms.

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

This is the final episode (I hope) of the long story named "How I usually handle iis related stuff"

Previous episodes: 
[Ep1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852061/silently-move-api-resources-to-another-url).
[Ep2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873404/reverse-proxy-on-azure-app-service).

So.

I've set up URL rewrite to handle the all main websites api requests with the reverse proxy and pass them to the new api behind the scene.

All works great except the case when the api (the new web app) returns status 401 (Because of the wrong token etc.).

The user should see the 401 Unauthorized but it tries to redirect him instead to the `"/login?returnUrl=some/api/url/which/returns/401/status"`.

As I understand It happened because of the fact that I have such authentication setup in `web.config` of the main website.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="100000" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
```

So the request workflow looks like this:

1. User requests `mainapp.com/api/some/endpoint`.
2. IIS handles it with URL rewrite and redirects to the `apiapp.com/api/some/endpoint`
3. apiapp.com handles it and returns 401 status
4. mainapp.com handles 401 status and returns 302 status with `/login?returnUrl=api/some/endpoint`

Why the p.4 happend? I just need to pass the response and make mainapp.com do not think of it at all.

Is it possible to solve it somehow?

Comment: What you are expecting is a Reverse Proxy behavior from mainapp.com. I reviewed your EP1, so I am assuming you have configured Reverse Proxy. However, this contradicts your point 2 as you mentioned here that the request is being redirected. It will help if you mention where the sites are hosted in Azure and the URL Rewrite sections for both the sites. Without these it is very difficult to say anything. Also you may want to enabled Failed Request tracing for the web app to investigate this further.

Comment: URL Rewrite only for the mainapp. Yes both on azure. No redirect, just rewrite.

Comment: So when you say Azure, is it Azure App Service or VM or cloud Service?

Comment: Azure App Service

Answer (score 0):

So according to your setup this is the request flow:

> **client ----> mainapp.com ----> apiapp.com**

According to your details Mainapp.com is setup as a reverse proxy. However, point 4 suggests otherwise. In order to be sure, can you enable **Failed Request Tracing** on both the web apps and review the logs.

This is a 2 step process,

1. Enable **Failed Request tracing** in the portal

   [image]
2. Add the following section to the web.config of your web app (**Root**):

This will help you understand what happened to the request.

Comment: I'm pretty much understand what causes the issue. This is the authentication section inside web.config of the main website. But anyway I'll try to verify failed requests.

Comment: So you have the '<authentication>' section in mainapp.com? If yes, then I will recommend you to review the entire setup.

Comment: Yes I have... I'd written that in the main question btw. The only thing I want to achieve is to handle all requests to the mainapp.com/api/* with apiapp.com/api/* and that's it.

Comment: My bad, I misread when you said main site. Eitherways, the **Failed Request Traces** will provide clarity on where the 302 came from.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. In my case, the culprit was in the mainapp.com's web.config. Specifically, authentication was set as required, and I had a redirect defined to login.aspx. The offending code was here:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

After commenting this out, I could prove that it was the mainapp.com that was handing the 401 Unauthorized returned from the proxied call to apiapp.com